# How do I grab SQLite row in UITableView based on ID? (Detailed)

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview

[image: SQLite error...]

Hello. I've been having a small problem retrieving data based on SQLite ID. This is the roadblock in my way before completing my application. I apologize for the large amount of code, but I really would appreciate some help.

If you take a look at the picture I provided, you can notice a few things:

I am getting an error when I select my second UITableCell. Precisely:

```
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

I am running the sqlite3 framework, and retrieving a query which displays just two items... (StoreName:Latin Bites Peruvian Cuisine , StoreAddr:5709 Woodway Dr)

That's what you see in my UITableView, which is coming out of one of my objects.

```
Company *aCompany;

aCompany = [arrayOfStore objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = aCompany.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = aCompany.address;
```

So what I've been trying to do is select a cell, and **retrieve data based on StoreID**.
However, I don't know how to select based on ID, so to test my application initially, I just called the first row that my SQLite db has. The code for the segue is as follows:

```
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &companyDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
        [arrayOfStore removeAllObjects];

        NSString *querySql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM storelist"];
        const char* query_sql = [querySql UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare(companyDB, query_sql, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {


                NSString *name = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];


                // set whatever you want here in your destination view controller


                [self retrieveData];


                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
                Company *currentStore = [arrayOfStore objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


                ReportsViewController *destinationVC = [segue destinationViewController];
                destinationVC.name = name;
                destinationVC.startDate = selectedStartDate;
                destinationVC.endDate = selectedEndDate;
                destinationVC.netSales = currentStore.netSales;
                destinationVC.voids = currentStore.voids;
                destinationVC.discounts = currentStore.discounts;
                destinationVC.guestCount = currentStore.guestCount;
                destinationVC.peopleServed = currentStore.peopleServed;
                destinationVC.employeeClockIn = currentStore.employeesClock;
```

That's for segueing, another important code you need is the

```
 [self retrieveData];
```

method.
**RetrieveData** =

```
- (void) retrieveData
{


sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &companyDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
    [arrayOfStore removeAllObjects];

    NSString *querySql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM storelist"];
    const char* query_sql = [querySql UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare(companyDB, query_sql, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {




            // Statement 1,2,3 etc. relates to the SQLite table in order.

            NSString *host = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
            NSString *pass = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6)];
            NSString *db = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 7)];




NSString *salesStr = @"http://";
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:host];
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:@":8080/sales.php?password="];
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:pass];
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:@"&db="];
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:db];
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:@"&sdate="];
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:[selectedStartDate stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:@"&edate="];
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:[selectedEndDate stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];




NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:salesStr];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];



json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];


NSLog(@"response type is %@",[json class]);

//Set up our cities array



arrayOfStore = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


{

    NSNumber * netSales = json[@"netSales"];
    NSNumber * voids = json[@"voidSales"];
    NSNumber * discounts = json[@"discountSales"];
    NSNumber * guestCount = json[@"guestCount"];
    NSNumber * servedCount = json[@"servedCount"];
    NSNumber * employeesClock = json[@"loggedIn"];

    NSString *netSalesString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",netSales];
    NSString *voidsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",voids];
    NSString *discountsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",discounts];
    NSString *guestCountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",guestCount];
    NSString *peopleServedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",servedCount];
    NSString *employeesClockString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",employeesClock];



    Company * myStore = [[Company alloc]initWithNetSales: (NSString *) netSalesString andVoids: (NSString *) voidsString andDiscounts: (NSString*) discountsString andGuestCount: (NSString *) guestCountString andPeopleServed: (NSString *) peopleServedString andEmployeesClock: (NSString  *) employeesClockString];




    [arrayOfStore addObject:myStore];
```

So *basically* what I'm doing is retrieving the data from the FIRST row **instead** of StoreID's row...

**My Question Is: How do I grab SQLite rows based on the *StoreID* instead of just the first entry in the SQLite db?...**

Would really appreciate the guidance
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just declaring currentStore as my objectAtIndex,

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
currentStore = [arrayOfStore objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

And then used this for my SQL code.

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT StoreID, StoreName, StoreAddr, StoreHost, StorePort, StoreUser, StorePass, StoreDB FROM storelist WHERE StoreID=%d", currentStore.storeID];
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, use a WHERE clause to filter out records you do not want:

```
SELECT host, pass, db
FROM storelist
WHERE StoreID = 123
```

(You should avoid `SELECT *`; your app is likely to blow up whenever the table structure changes.)

Comment: Thank you for the response! This is starting to make more sense to me.

Comment: Any advice on NSLogging this particular section? And would 

    SELECT StoreID, StoreHost, StorePass, StoreDB FROM storelist ORDER BY StoreID

Work?

Comment: Log whatever you want. To check whether a query works, try it out. (This might be easier with the `sqlite3` command-line shell.)